# TreeMap with as its value a TreeSet, how to remove element from this TreeSet?

Tags: java, element, treemap, treeset

I have a TreeMap, where the values are TreeSet. Now  I need to loop through the keys, and for each element of the TreeSet I have to delete that element (then continue to do something) and then delete the second element of that TreeSet etc.

I tried:

```
for (Integer w : adjacencyList.get(keyNow)){        
    adjacencyList.get(keyNow).remove(w);
}
```

this doesn't work, could somebody please help?

Comment: Have you considered using Guava's multiset (https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit iterator :

```
if (adjacencyList.containsKey(keyNow)) {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = adjacencyList.get(keyNow).iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Integer w = iter.next();
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain why my code gave errors? Because it seems to me that the new and old code work both in sort of the same way, but I can't grasp exactly why the old one did not work..

Comment: @Jorane Removing an element from a Set while iterating over it with the enhanced for loop is not allowed, since the enhanced for loop creates its own iterator, and removing the element invalidates the state of that iterator. Using Iterator's remove method while iterating with an explicit iterator overcomes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Eran's answer but I would write it like this.

```
Set<Integer> ints = adjacencyList.get(keyNow);
if (ints != null) {
    for (Iterator<Integer> iter = ints.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
         Integer w = iter.next();
         // do something with w
         iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Note: if you don't need to examine each value you can just clear the set.

```
Set<Integer> ints = adjacencyList.get(keyNow);
if (ints != null)
    ints.clear(); // remove all.
```